# Is there any reward for completing the Kanto and Galar research tasks?

Tags: pokemon-home

In the Switch version of Pokemon Home, there are a few "Research Tasks" in the Pokedex section of the application, which you can complete by transferring certain Pokemon to Home from the Switch games. Is there any reward for completing the tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment in time, there are currently no rewards for completing these research tasks (confirmed [here](https://www.polygon.com/guides/2020/2/13/21136297/pokemon-home-research-tasks-guide) and [here](https://gamerjournalist.com/pokemon-home-research-tasks/)). The research tasks are designed to provide additional feeling of accomplishment as you fill your Pokemon Home's dex.